# List affecting menu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have two pages, let's use http://codepixl.net/indesx.shtml (indesx instead of index cause the site's under construction) and http://codepixl.net/experiments . If you go to the pages on a 768px wide or smaller device, the you'll have a menu icon in the corner, and when you click/tap it, a menu opens. However, on http://codepixl.net/experiments (Which has a list) the menu looks like this:[image: The menu is not right.]

And obviously it's a bit too far down. It's supposed to look like this:
[image]

I've determined that the /experiments page's css doesn't cause this, it's the nav's css. Also, the menu icon's color changed because of the page's style. I am using an SSI include to add the menu. Here's the menu's css: http://codepixl.net/stylesheets/nav.css

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
#cssmenu {top: 0;}
```

But the issue is caused by the default top margin on the `h1`, so you could also do this:

```
h1 {margin-top: 0;}
```

But that's not really what you want.

You can also specify the hamburger color directly:

```
#menubutton {color: #333;}
```

Comment: Thanks! And I knew how to specify the hamburger color :)